# ng2-pagination not firing page change

Tags: angular, pagination

So I am getting started with Angular2 and am trying to add pagination through the ng2-pagination component, after a lot of trial and error I have reached the stage where my data appears correctly, the pagination control appears correctly but the page change is not being fired, so I always stay on the first page.

Here is my html

```
  <div id="item_box" *ngFor="let item of listItems | paginate: 
           {itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: page};">
             <! -- Elements to display my data items, all works OK -->
  </div>

    <div id="pager" class="pagination">
       <pagination-template #p="paginationApi" (pageChange)="pageChange.emit($event)">

       <ul>
          <li [class.disabled]="p.isFirstPage()">
               <a (click)="p.setCurrent(1)">First</a>
           </li>
           <li [class.disabled]="p.isFirstPage()">
               <a (click)="p.previous()">Previous</a>
            </li>


            <li *ngFor="let page of p.pages" [class.current]="p.getCurrent() === page.value">
                <a (click)="p.setCurrent(page.value)">{{page.value}}</a>
             </li>
             <li [class.disabled]="p.isLastPage()">
                 <a (click)="p.next()">Next</a>
             </li>
             <li [class.disabled]="p.isLastPage()">
                  <a (click)="p.getLastPage()">Last</a>
              </li>
         </ul>
    </pagination-template>
</div>
```

Visually everything looks fine.

Any my list.component code

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";

import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/pagination';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  listItems = [];
  private subscription: Subscription;

@Input() id: string;
@Input() page;
@Input() maxSize: number;

@Output() pageChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private apiService:ApiService, private router:Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)
  {

  }

  ngOnInit()
  {
     //Code removed for brevity, but here I execute WS and get data here, populated in this.listItems
     this.listItems == result;
     ...
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I get no errors.  but when I click to change the page nothing happens.

I'm sure that it must be something simple, something that I have missed somewhere but what and where?

The examples/code on https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination don't help and any other examples I find also don't help.

Any ideas?  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Hi. I'm the lib author. Question: in the PaginatePipe you set `currentPage: page` - I don't see a "page" var in your code. Is it passed in as an Input? Currently your code just seems to re-emit the pageChange event, but I cannot see any part that would actually change the value of "page" - which must happen in order for the pagination to work correctly.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes I had it in my class but missed it from the code above (copy past problem).  But this pointed me in the right direction, and I have solved the issue.  See the answer I posted below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after many more hours I have managed to solve the issue.

I could not get it working with the emitter but in my html I changed this;

```
<pagination-template #p="paginationApi" (pageChange)="pageChange.emit($event)">
```

to this

```
<pagination-template #p="paginationApi" (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)">
```

In my code I then added this;

```
  onPageChange(e)
  {
    if (e)
      this.page = e;
  }
```

Then I had an issue with the variable `page` not being initialised, so I added this in my constructor

```
this.page = 1;
```

I'm not sure why the emitter won't work, due to my lack of experience with Angular then I couldn't find this out, but this now works for me.

And the proof of a good working solution is that I was able to add the pagination into another component and it also worked first time with no problems!

Answer (score 0):

can u check the list of items ? 
(for example if u have 9 items and the itemsPerPage = 10) surely it'll do nothing :) 
please verify the request that sent to server

Comment: No that's not the issue.  I have tried this on different lists with different number of items, and for testing I have limited the number of items per page to 3.  And despite having > 20 items, I have the issue.  The number of pages shown in the pagination is correct according to the number of items i have (and varies for each list correctly)

Comment: I'm using the same library and it works fine. However I communicate with the server using http. The request contains (itemsPerPage and currentPage) and the response contains (totalItems in the server and the items linked to this page), in your case items are statics, so it takes only the first items every request.

Comment: I'm not sure if the pagination works with a static list of items (because the idea behind is getting a full list in segments)

Comment: The items are not static, they are retrieved via a webservice (see //Code removed for brevity).  But I am not doing server pagination.  The whole list is retrieved and stored in listItems

Comment: Ok. in the official documentation : totalItems [number] The total number of items in the collection. Only useful when doing server-side paging, where the collection size is limited to a single page returned by the server API. For in-memory paging, this property should not be set, as it will be automatically set to the value of collection.length. so try to remove "totalItems" :)

Comment: if u want to use totalItems u should doing server pagination (check this  :  https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination)

Comment: I don't have "totalItems" set!  This does not appear in my code.  And as I already the said, the examples on michaelbromley's page does not help